# How to use .searchfiles() in google script custom function?

Tags: google-sheets

I have currently written some google script to find a file whose title contains a certain date and then pull the URL from that spreadsheet file. Here is my current code.

```
function FindID(InvoiceDate) {
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(InvoiceDate);
  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log('Name:'+file.getName()+'\nURl'+ file.getUrl());
}
```

when I try to use the function, I get an error "you do not have permissions to call driveapp.searchfiles()". When I was looking around other questions, I gathered that I might not be able to use this in a custom function? Are there any workarounds or different approaches to my goal?

Comment: In the current stage, when the methods which are required to authorize are used in the custom function, such error occurs. It seems that this is the current specification at Google side. So for example, as the workaround, this information is useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63553532/7108653 https://stackoverflow.com/q/62205747/7108653 https://github.com/tanaikech/Enhanced-Custom-Function-for-Google-Spreadsheet-using-Web-Apps-as-Wrapper

Comment: Why don't you run it as a regular function ? Namely, execute it from the script editor or as a menu ? The input can be fed by the sheet itself. Put the information in a cell and then run the script.

Comment: @Tanaike I believe that I will try to use the code shared from Github. I believe the first function might work; I would like to find a specific file in the folder (title contains invoicedate) and retrieve the URL from that file, is this possible/do you have suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: @Marios I get the error "you do not have the permission..." when I use it in a menu. I believe this is a Google privacy restriction that does not allow for the .searchfiles() function to be called in custom functions specifically. Please let me know if I misunderstand you; I am very new to google script in general.

Comment: Is the file you want to get on your drive or you can enter it from the UI?

Comment: @Kessy the file I want is in my drive

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I would like to find a specific file in the folder (title contains invoicedate) and retrieve the URL from that file, is this possible/do you have suggestions on how to do it?`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? Do you have any updates on the issue?

Comment: @Kessy I believe I figured out a workaround, creating a custom menu from the UI allows me to use the function. Thanks all!

Comment: @RyanCapule Could you share your workaround so more people benefits from it?

Comment: I made an onOpen() function and created a custom menu that can call the function in the original post. This allows the searchFiles() to work. function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var searchMenuEntries = [ {name: "Function Title", functionName: "Function}];
  ss.addMenu("Print...", searchMenuEntries);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the asking user:

I made an `onOpen()` function and created a custom menu that can call the function in the original post.

This allows the searchFiles() to work.

```
function onOpen() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var searchMenuEntries = [ {name: "Function Title", functionName: "Function"}]; 
  ss.addMenu("Print...", searchMenuEntries);
}
```